# pixel value changed after rewrite the video

Tags: video, opencv, colors, osx-snow-leopard, pixel

I have videos which are grayscale (x-ray) ... 
the problem is when I read and write the videos the pixel value change !!! 
I print the pixel values as a gray and as BGR and I got values in all of them ... 
I read the video then I write it using openCV then I re print the pixel value and I see different in the pixel values !!!

I am using openCV 2.4.3 with FFMPEG 0.11 on MAC 10.6.8

why the pixel value changed ? ... how can I read and write the video without changing the pixel value? 
BTW: the original videos has been written in windows using FFMPEG with YUV240 pixel format !

Thanks in Advance :D

Comment: Most likely because the resulting video didn't use a lossless compression. You need to ensure that.

Comment: the resulting video use the same codec which is FFV1 (lossless)

Comment: First of all, your video is not grayscale if you have RGB data with different values for a given pixel in the different channels. Second, the way you are showing the "gray value" is incorrect since you are not multiplying the index `i` by 3 (the frame is in BGR). Lastly, if you are attempting to save grayscale data as rgb, can you guarantee that there is no intermediate step that slightly modifies the original values ? Here is a way to save this data correctly: save each frame as png, group them in a lossless video format by using ffmpeg.

Comment: I am using the same method to access pixel value in this linke [link] (http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/faq#How_to_access_image_pixels)
there is no intermediate step !! if you commet out the check_frame_type function . the program will read the video and write it as it is without any change in the pixel values

Comment: You are just misreading things, and I'm going to stop commenting here till it seems you have put some effort into it. From the link to the faq pointed by yourself: "Suppose, we have 8-bit 1-channel image: ...", the code that follows is irrelevant because you don't have a 8-bit 1-channel image, instead you have 3-channel image. Regarding the intermediate step, I'm talking about internal workings of the encoders that OpenCV hide from you.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding ...how can I read and write the video without changing in the pixel values ?

Comment: please any idea ? ... I waste month just in this problem ... I am not sure how can I read and write the video without changing in the pixel value ... I tried FFMPEG code . but I face problem on it ... I see the openCV deal easily with the videos ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pixels values change because openCV convert the frames to BGR by default ! 
the reading operation do the conversion process , I guess , that why the pixels change

I hope this can help who face this problem , to get the exact value , you can read and write the videos using FFMPEG which provide a lot of pixel format